# GeoServer JSON URL valid on browser, but not valid on Python `requests`

Tags: python, geoserver, json

I go to my GeoServer URL as JSON and I can see the JSON file, but when I pass in to `requests` module. This is my Python code:

```py
import requests

baseurl = "http://someserver.com/geoserver/workspace/ows"
params = {
    'service': 'WFS', 
    'version': '1.0.0', 
    'request': 'GetFeature', 

    # I censored the name with xxxx, it should be other alphabet, but the underscroe remains
    'typeName': 'amxxxxx:nexxxx_froxxxx', 

    'maxFeature': 5, 

    # it is an SQL view and I am passing parameter to the layer
    'viewparams': 'x:10.2;y:4.5;a:some_string_with_underscore6969;b:another_with_number69;', 
    'outputFormat': 'application/json'
}

r = requests.get(baseurl, params=params)
print(r.text)
```

it yield the following error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.0.0/OGCexception.xsd">

<ServiceException code="InvalidParameterValue" locator="typeName">

Feature type amxxxxx:nexxxx_froxxxx unknown

</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

but then, I checked the URL by printing `print(r.url)` which results this URL:

```
http://someserver.som/geoserver/workspace/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=amxxxxx%3Anexxxx_froxxxx&maxFeature=5&viewparams=x%3A10.2%3By%3A4.5%3Ba%3Asome_string_with_underscore6969%3Bb%3Aanother_with_number69%3B&outputFormat=application%2Fjson
```

I can literally see the JSON data in my browser! It looks like this in my browser

```json
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"nexxxx_froxxxx.fid-122ff51_aewfadsfasdf","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-1.23417,55.22331]},"geometry_name":"the_geom","properties":{"id":908}}],"totalFeatures":1,"numberMatched":1,"numberReturned":1,"timeStamp":"2022-08-31T13:29:58.706Z","crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::404000"}}}
```

So, why does my browser receive the JSON data from the GeoServer URL, but not with the requests module? It's literally the same URL!

Answer (score 1):

it's an authentication error.

I went to my geoserver dashboard > layer > (click my layer that I tried to query with `requests`) > security > check the read only and write checkbox.

Comment: And I guess you were logged in as admin in the browser

Comment: indeed. I didn't realise this was a factor, spent 2 hours figuring out my codes.

Comment: That's why I always use curl for testing, rather than the browser